# How to add attributes in cart popup?

Tags: cart, sidebar, magento1.9.2.4

I am using magento1.9.2.4.

I want to include the attributes like color and size in my cart popup. Please someone guide me to do that.
Below is my code in `sidebar/default.phtml` :

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
$_product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
?>

<p class="product-name"><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?><a
        href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php endif; ?><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?></a><?php endif; ?>
</p>
<p class="product-color">

    <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()): ?>
    <div class="truncated">
        <div class="truncated_full_value">
            <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?php if (is_array($_option['value'])): ?>
                            <?php echo nl2br(implode("\n", $_option['value'])) ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo $_option['value'] ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details"><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></a>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
</p>
<strong class="qty">Qty <?php echo $this->getQty() ?></strong>
```

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: am using magento1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Either in your local.xml or the layout xml file for your custom module, if you have one, you will declare a template renderer. You do not need to include all of the ones below if you are just trying to do this for a specific product type. In that case, just add the renderer for the specific product type following the example below.

```
<default>
    <reference name="minicart_content">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>path/to/custom/items/renderer.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>path/to/custom/items/renderer.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>path/to/custom/items/renderer.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>path/to/custom/items/renderer.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Then, you need to create the actual renderer. You can either copy Magento's renderer into your own custom file and edit it as needed or you can create an entirely new renderer from scratch. For this example, I assumed that you like the current item renderer and just want to add some data to it. I have tested this before posting. Keep in mind that if the attribute you want to display is not present when you call upon `$this->getProduct()->getData()`, you may need to load the product to get the attribute data.

```
<?php
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);

?>
<li class="item" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="product-details">
        <p class="product-name"><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php endif; ?><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?></a><?php endif; ?></p>

        <table class="info-wrapper">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Color'); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $this->__($this->getProduct()->getColor()); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Price'); ?></th>
                <td>
                    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>

                        <span class="map-cart-sidebar-item"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>

                    <?php else: ?>

                        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales')): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                                <br />
                                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales')): ?>
                                    <small>
                                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </small>
                                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales')): ?>
                                    <small>
                                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </small>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>



                        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
                            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                                <br /><?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>:
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales')): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                                <br />
                                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales')): ?>
                                    <small>
                                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </small>
                                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales')): ?>
                                    <small>
                                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                                            <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </small>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales')): ?>
                                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php endif; //Can apply MSRP ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="qty-wrapper">
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Qty'); ?></th>
                <td>
                    <input
                        id="qinput-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
                        data-link="<?php echo $this->getAjaxUpdateUrl() ?>"
                        data-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
                        data-cart-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getSku(); ?>"
                        class="qty cart-item-quantity input-text" name=""
                        value="<?php echo $this->getQty()?>"
                        <?php if ($this->isOnCheckoutPage()) echo 'disabled'; ?>
                    />

                    <button id="qbutton-<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
                            data-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>"
                            disabled="disabled"
                            data-update
                            data-cart-item-update
                            class="button quantity-button">
                        <?php echo $this->__('ok'); ?>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <?php if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getConfigureUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Edit item')) ?>" class="btn-edit">
                <?php echo $this->__('Edit item')?>
            </a>
            |
            <?php if (!$this->isOnCheckoutPage()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getAjaxDeleteUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Remove This Item')) ?>"
                   data-confirm="<?php echo $this->__('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?') ?>"
                   class="remove">
                    <?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?>
                </a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif ?>



        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
            <div class="truncated">
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                            <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (is_array($_option['value'])): ?>
                                    <?php echo nl2br(implode("\n", $_option['value'])) ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php echo $_option['value'] ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details"><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: In which file exactly should I add this code? And I just want be clear that I just need to display the attributes value in cart pop up ie sidebar.phtml.

Comment: You have to create your own file. Based on your question, it sounds like you have not created a module which is fine. 

You can create `app/design/frontend/package/theme/layout/local.xml` and `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/somefolder/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml`

Comment: yea exactly.should i copy your full code into `sidebar/default.phtml` ?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. Its just the default code from magento and then I only added 4 lines to it.             `<tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->__('Color'); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $this->__($this->getProduct()->getColor()); ?></td>
            </tr>`

Comment: I followed your guidance but instead of displaying the color of the product, it is just displaying as `COLOR`. the value inside `td` is not getting displayed.only `th` is showing up. Kindly help

Comment: "Color" is the label for the attribute. Please note that in my original answer I stated that if the attribute data you seek is not showing up you may need to call ->load() on the product.

Comment: I gave this line `<td><?php echo $this->__($this->getProduct()->load()->getColor()); ?></td>` but didnt work.

Comment: You wouldn't do it that way but also the call to load requires a product id to be passed in.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. I modified my code like below to display the configurable attribute (color, size) in cart popup:

```
    <?php
    $_item = $this->getItem();
    $isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
    $canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
    $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
?>

        <p class="product-name"><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php endif; ?><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()): ?></a><?php endif; ?></p>
    <p class="attri-value">  
        <?php $options = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct()); ?>
        <?php $product = $_item->getProduct(); ?>
     <?php 
            foreach($options['attributes_info'] as $key => $value){ 
            echo ' '.$value['value'];
            } 
    ?>
   </p>
    <strong class="qty">Qty <?php echo $this->getQty() ?></strong>
```